# What are the advantages and disadvantages of explicitly specifying collation in table creation scripts?

Tags: sql, collation

When creating a table, the COLLATE clause is optional. So, in:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
  F1 varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NOT NULL,
  F2 varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

the collation of F2 will be determined by the database default.

In the past our team always used the default collation. However, we now have a few columns where we need to explicitly specify collation. We are considering whether to change our standard to *always* specify collation and looking for any additional information that may help in this decision.

So:

- What are the advantages/disadvantages of always specifying collation?
- Are there any gotchas we need to watch out for if we always specify collation?

Possibly relevant additional information:

- We deploy to multiple clients, and not all clients will be upgraded at the same time.
- Some clients do have different collation configurations on their servers.
- Our applications use Ansi strings, and any consideration of Unicode is a **very** long way away.
- We use MS SQL Server 2005 and up (although I would prefer to keep the question general to any platform supporting collations if possible).

**Please Note**: This question is **not** asking about how to resolve collation conflicts, or change existing server/database/column collations. (There are plenty of those already.)

Comment: Why database default collation is not enough for you? If you need a different collation than default for a column then you need to write it, I don't understand your question. Disadvantage is write for both same information but I think that this is not your case.

Answer (score 2):

You are building an application that deploys on client machines.  You should be explicit about your collations.

For instance, the default collation is case insensitive.  If the client -- for whatever reason -- prefers to have case sensitivity be the default in their database, then comparisons will differ on different machines.

You also have the issue of debugging.  If the client is getting results in one sequential order, your test/development system may get them in a different order.  This can hamper debugging and customer support.

In the end, it is probably better to have consistent software on your side for debugging, maintenance, and support.  If a particular client needs data in a different format, then customize the system for that client.

Comment: +1 I'm very much in favour of consistency: consistently wrong is much better than sometimes right, sometimes wrong. But isn't the consistency the same so long as each database at each client uses the same default collation?

Comment: The questioner explicitly states that the default collation sequences are different at different customers.  Presumably, this is because the customer can control that aspect of the database.

Comment: @CraigYoung, you are right.  You can keep the same default collation, if you control that.  The way I understood your question, it seemed that you didn't control it.  You might explicitly set the default collation as part of the SQL Server configs, to be sure that it is your default.

Answer (score 0):

there is no point to specify colation if it is tha same as the database's colation (the default). You should do what you did on your example only if you want to store the data on F1 on a different collation

Comment: One of clients' server collation was different to the database collation. This created a problem when temp tables (created in tempdb using its default collation) could not be compared with data in our database. The solution was straight-forward enough: we now create temp tables forcing collation to the default of our database. But it was a surprise that would have been nice to avoid.