# Check value if exist with uppercase and lowercase letters

Tags: php, pdo

I want to check if username exists in Database but I have problem Ex : If I have username = jack and another register with username = JaCk

It accepts 
I want to check the full username with lowercase and uppercase and refuse such cases (jack - Jack - JaCk ....)

```
$stmtr = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username");
$stmtr->bindparam(":username", $val['username']);
$stmtr->execute();
$row=$stmtr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($rowr['username']==$val['username']) {
echo "Exists";
}
```

Comment: What database server software is in use?

Comment: What did you set for collation? You also don't need a second comparison, if you get a result it matched..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if( strtolower($row['username'])==strtolower($val['username']) ) { echo "Exists";}
```

You can also replace `strtolower` with `strtoupper` that will convert a string to upper case.

**NOTE:** That for this case `strtolower` and `strtoupper` will result in the same outcome as noted by @user3783243

Also if your trying to compare both values with `Case Sensitivity` that is you don't want `if('JAck'== 'jAck')` to return **true** then use strict comparison `===`

```
 if('JAck'== 'jAck') //will return true
 if('JAck'=== 'jAck') //will retrun false
```

Comment: OP asks for reverse. He wants to check for upper and lowercase.

Comment: i understand the misconception but do consider this line in the question **If I have username = jack and another register's with username = JaCk It accepts**

Comment: Okay, guess that was inverted, `strtoupper` should be removed though, it will have the same affect as `tolower`.

Comment: @user3783243 yes that's true just letting the user know he can use that as well.

Comment: @BobbyAxe This answer your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873771/how-to-prevent-xss-attacks-in-php

Comment: @Havenard thanks i wanted to improve the original question but on second thought i deleted it thanks for the info i have been doing a lot of reading on it if you think its still useful you can vote for it to be opened though

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo. In line:

```
if($rowr['username']==$val['username']) {
```

it should be:

```
if($row['username']==$val['username']) {
```

Also, by default, MySQL performs case-insensitive query. Note the `_ci` part in your DB collation (e.g. `utf8_general_ci`), it means case insensitive. You have to perform extra checking in PHP to check for different upper- and lowercase.

Comment: Changing the collations is also an option, then just need to check if there is a result.

Comment: @Raptor whats is perform extra checking in PHP to check for different upper- and lowercase. ?? thats whats I want

Comment: @user3783243 Agree, but for compatibility and migration-ability, I suggest to use case-insensitive collations. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578591/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-explicitly-specifying-collation-in) for discussion in details.

Comment: The PHP comparison checking `==` already can check for upper and lowercase. i.e. `'Jack' == 'jack'` will return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `UPPER_CASE` in SQL query:

```
$stmtr = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE UPPER(username)=:username");
$stmtr->bindparam(":username", strtoupper($val['username']));
```

But I think you should store `username` as uppercase or lowercase when user register. It is better than using `UPPER` in SQL